# SIMULINK not recognizing variables defined in Annotation Box (Mablab 2018a)

Tags: variables, simulink

I'm using what should be a working example for a MATLAB/SIMULINK toolbox. However, variable written in an annotation box are bot recognized by the simulink blocks. I'm using MATLAB 2018a, and I'm wondeing if this is due to the version and how can I resolve this issue so variables can be defined in the annotation?

[Showing Error and annotation text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo17P.png)

[Block with missing variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM33A.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables need to be defined in the MATLAB Workspace.  Simply writing some text into an annotation isn't enough - there they are only treated as text.

You can move your text to the `ClickFcn` box, check the `Use annotation text as ClickFcn Callback` checkbox, and then click on the annotation to have the code executed.
Or I would suggest it would be better to have a script that initializes all parameters, and which you run before running the model.